# Select all items with a field nonempty

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I am trying to select all the rows from a table with a field non-empty. My sql query is

```
SELECT * FROM coupon_category WHERE customer=4 AND like_at <>;
```

But its shows syntax error in the end. What is the correct query? like_at is a datetime type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `like_at` is a string, a simple way is:

```
WHERE customer = 4 AND like_at <> ''
```

Of course, it depends on what you mean by non-empty.

This would normally refer to `NULL`, so for any type would be:

```
WHERE customer = 4 AND like_at IS NOT NULL
```

Note:  The first version also filters out `NULL` values as well as empty strings (assuming the type of `like_at` is a string).

Comment: it is a date time type

Comment: @raju . . . Then "empty" presumably means `NULL` and the second form is what to use.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to exclude blanks, and potentially nulls, try:

```
SELECT * FROM coupon_category WHERE customer=4 AND ifnull(like_at,'') <> '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Query interpreter expects a value after <> signs.
If you want to select all rows with a field not empty, you should do:

```
SELECT * FROM coupon_category WHERE customer=4 AND like_at <> '';
```

Maybe you may check null values also.

Answer (score 0):

That depends what happend when like_at is empty, wthen the "cell" is empty it gives you null?

If the cell is empty u can use

```
  SELECT * FROM coupon_category WHERE customer=4 AND len(like_at)>0
```

And if it gave you null then :

```
  SELECT * FROM coupon_category WHERE customer=4 AND like_at is not null
```